# angular tinymce missing features

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tinymce

I am using [angular-ui-tinymce](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-tinymce)

Which gives me the following editor:

[image]

However this editor is lacking a lot of features such as `tables` and `links`

Does anyone know how to add these to the control or will i have to use the jquery version of it?

Answer (score 1):

you can add following code in your controller

```
$scope.tinymceOptions = {
        menubar: true,
        toolbar: "bold italic underline styleselect link",
        statusbar: true,
        theme: "modern",
        plugins: "link autolink"
    };
```

You have to bind tinymceOptions to your tag where you want to do editing